# How to open Webview on top layer of my activity? (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I have a problem to add a webview after I use startactivity. I have an intent and start it :

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    String uriString = uri.toString();
    String extension = uriString.substring(uriString.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    intent.setClass(this, extensionToActivity.get(extension));
    startActivity(intent);
```

after my activity ran completely, I need to open a webview so I go to Oncreate function and add my code

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
     WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);         
            String summary = "<html><body><h1>some test</h1></body></html>";
            wv.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
            wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

but my program crash!!! but if i show alert inside onCreat it works fine, what is the problem?

what is the problem?

Comment: have you set `setContentView` in oncreate?

Comment: i did, same result, this is what i get from my log, or maybe i set contentview in a wrong place? '09-23 18:16:38.260: E/AndroidRuntime(9562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 18:16:38.260: E/AndroidRuntime(9562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.vudroid/org.vudroid.pdfdroid.PdfViewerActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
09-23 18:16:38.260: E/AndroidRuntime(9562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the Intent that I work uses another activity inside, this is because my program crash. I found that activity and add my webview there, now it is solved

```
setContentView(R.layout.browseritems);
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);         
String summary = "<html><body><h1>some test</h1></body></html>";
wv.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set layout by using `setContentView()` method. FYI, You can't find any views without setting content views to activity.

Comment: i used 'setContentView' after 'StartActivity', same, even inside onCreate , again same!\

Comment: if i open webview after 'startactivity' it opens but i need run my intent first.

Comment: What do you mean by `same`?  And what do you want to do exactly by starting activity and inside WebView activity?

Comment: OK, `same` means still crash even with `setContentView. And, I show a  PDF file by `StartActivity`, but i need to open a `WebView` on top to control interaction too. but i cannot open `Webview` after PDF was shown!

Comment: Think again on the things you are trying to implement.

Comment: I have to do like this. Because my costumer has some pages in but wants to show it in webview, there are more than 20,000 webpages and doing double things is costly, so I have to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);         
            String summary = "<html><body><h1>some test</h1></body></html>";
            wv.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
            wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

EDIT:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```